# how to use php scripts in datalife engine template files?

Tags: datalife-engine

I want to read and display something from the database on the DataLife Engine homepage with php script. 
Something like the last few news shows.

But when I call the file containing the PHP script inside the DataLife Engine template files (with the .tpl extension) (like this:{include file="test.tpl"}), this script don't work and don't show anything.

when I call the php file like this ({include file="test.php"}) in .tpl files, Data-Life-Engine show me an error with this description: Include files from root directory is denied.

Please help me to use a PHP script in the DataLife-Engine template file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first you must put your PHP file in the path "engine/modules".
Then call it in your template file as follows:

```
{include file="engine/modules/TEST.php"}
```